# Progress bar in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine application that performs about 30-50 calls to a remote API.  Each call takes about a second, so the whole operation can easily take a minute.  Currently, I do this in a loop inside the post() function of my site, so the response isn't printed until the whole operation completes.  Needless to say, the app isn't very usable at the moment.

What I would like to do is to print the response immediately after the operation is started, and then update it as each individual API call completes.  How would I achieve this?  On a desktop application, I would just kick off a worker thread that would periodically update the front-end.  Is there a similar mechanism in the Google App Engine?

I googled around for "progress bar" and "google app engine" but most results are from people that want to monitor the progress of uploading a file.  My situation is different: the time-consuming task is being performed on the server, so there isn't much the client can do to monitor its progress.  [This guy](http://blog.thibaultpouget.com/2011/01/background-progress-with-channel-api.html) is the closest thing I could find, but he works in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Send the post logic to a task using http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue
2. Change the logic of the process to set a status (it could be using memcache)
3. Using AJAX query memcache status each 10 seconds, more or less, it's up to you

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I went with the taskqueue, and pushed updates using the Channel API (as @Moishe also mentioned).  On the client side, I wrote JavaScript to consume the messages and update the front end.

Comment: Some pseudo code example would be very helpfull to others. I am having the same problem now.

Answer (score 3):

You could return immediately from your post, and do one of two things:

- Poll from your client every second or so to ask your service for its status
- Use the Channel API to push status updates down to your client

Comment: It's good to hear that pushing and pulling updates still works in Google App Store land, but can you be a little more specific?  Examples would be really great.  Thank you.  The first option sounds particularly good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: Use a task queue that writes to a memcache key as the operation progresses. Your page can then either use the channel API or repeatedly poll the server for a progress report.

Long version: In your post you delegate the big job to a task. The task will periodically update a key that resides in memcache. If you don't have the time to learn the channel API, you can make the page returned by your post to periodically GET some URL in the app that returns a progress report based on the memcache data and you can then update your progress bar. When the job is complete your script can go to a results page.

If you have the time, learning the Channel API is worth the effort. In this case, the task would receive the channel token so it could communicate with the JavaScript channel client in your page without the polling thing.