# How to show progress for a running google app engine task queue task?

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

I currently try to understand the task queue of google app engine (gae).

I have a problem which is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240597/progress-bar-in-google-app-engine)

Therefore I coded a small app according to the solution of "chachan".

So my main problem is how to Poll the progress value from the html-site.

I wrote a small "Hello gae task queue" app which takes a number from a user
and prints this number mulitplied with all number from 1 to 10. The calculation is done by the task-queue.
The source is the following:

```
#hellogaequeue.py

import os
import time
import webapp2
import jinja2
import logging
import json
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
JINJA_ENV = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)


myresults = []      # the results of the task in a list
myProgressValue = 0 # represents the progess of the task. range[ 0, 100 ]

#define the main handler to show the html-site and post some data to the task.
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #gets the calculated results of the task (therefor empty at first call)
        #and give it to the jinja2 framework to render the html page
        template_values = {'myresults': myresults}
        counter_template = JINJA_ENV.get_template('counter.html')
        self.response.out.write(counter_template.render(template_values))

    # if user clicks the button, we write the data from the input field onto 'key' and
    # than add a new task, with the parameter holding the value of 'key'
    def post(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')

        # Add the task to the default queue.
        taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'key': key})
        self.redirect('/')  #calls MainHandler.get(...),  which shows than 'counter.html' again

#define the handler for the task worker
class TaskWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self): 
        # ensure to use the global variables
        global myresults
        global myProgressValue

        # get the 'params={'key': key}' value
        key = self.request.get('key')

        #now imagine this for loop takes 5 minutes to finish
        #how to show the progress of this loop in 'counter.html'
        for x in xrange(1, 11):
            time.sleep(1)
            res = x*int(key)
            myresults.append(str(res))
            myProgressValue = myProgressValue + 10


class ProgressWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global myProgressValue

        logging.info("Call to ProgressHandler. MyProgressValue is = {p}".format(p=myProgressValue))

        json_result = json.dumps({ "progress" : myProgressValue } )
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        self.response.out.write(json_result)


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication( [ ('/', MainHandler),  ('/worker', TaskWorker), ('/progress', ProgressWorker) ], debug=True)
```

The source of 'counter.html' is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello gae task queue with jQuery UI Progressbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="key" id="key">
        <input type="submit" value="start gae task">
    </form>

    {% for counter in myresults %}
        <li>
         {{counter}}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

    <div id="progressbar"></div>

    <div id="dbg"></div>

    <script>
        function refresh() 
        {
            var progressVal = 0

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/progress',
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    progressVal = obj.progress;
                    document.getElementById("dbg").innerHTML = obj.progress;
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) 
                {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(error);
                }
            });

            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar(
            {
                value: progressVal
            });
        }

        $(function()
        {
            setInterval("refresh()", 3000);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, the first question is:
Why is the  [jquerys progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) not working?
(There are no alerts.)
What Am I doing wrong?

The second question is:
Is this the right way to do it?
Considering that the for-loop takes more time than 60 seconds. Therefore it is not possible to put it in the MainHandler.post(..) function, because this will throw a Deadline exceeded error. 
And i should also mention that the for-loop could not run Concurrent.

Extra info:
The folder structure of my gae project is :

```
hellogaequeue
    -templates
         -counter.html
    -app.yaml
    -hellogaequeue.py
    -queue.yaml
```

and the app.yaml looks like:

```
application: queuetest-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hellogaequeue.application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working.

1.) The problem was that the referenced Jquery libs seem not to work properly for the progressbar.
(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348046/jquery-ui-progressbar-not-showing/26299857#26299857) for a better explanation)

So here is the final source of a "hello task queue whith jquery progress bar" app:

```
import os
import time
import webapp2
import jinja2
import json
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
JINJA_ENV = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)


myresults = []
myProgressValue = 0 #range[ 0, 100 ]


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {'myresults': myresults, 'progressScriptActive':False}
        counter_template = JINJA_ENV.get_template('counter.html')
        self.response.out.write(counter_template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        # Add the task to the default queue.
        taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'key': key})

        template_values = {'myresults': myresults, 'progressScriptActive':True}
        counter_template = JINJA_ENV.get_template('counter.html')
        self.response.out.write(counter_template.render(template_values))


class TaskWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self): 
        global myresults
        global myProgressValue

        key = self.request.get('key')
        for x in xrange(1, 11):
            time.sleep(1)
            res = x*int(key)
            myresults.append(str(res))
            myProgressValue = myProgressValue + 10


class ProgressWorker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global myProgressValue

        json_result = json.dumps( myProgressValue )
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        self.response.out.write(json_result)


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [
        ('/', MainHandler),
        ('/worker', TaskWorker),
        ('/progress', ProgressWorker)
    ], debug=True)
```

and the HTML jinja2 Template ("counter.html"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello gae task queue with jQuery UI Progressbar</title>
    <script src="/static/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text"  name="key" id="key">
        <input type="submit"  value="start gae task">
    </form>

    {% for counter in myresults %}
        <li>
         {{counter}}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="dbg"></div>

<script> 

    var intervalHandler = 0;

    function refresh() 
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/progress',
            success: function(data) 
            {   
                var progressVal = $.parseJSON( data );
                document.getElementById("dbg").innerHTML = progressVal;   

                if( progressVal > 99 )
                {
                    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( { value: 100 });
                    alert("Finish");

                    clearInterval(intervalHandler); // stop the interval
                    intervalHandler = null;

                    //window.location.reload(true);// will perform a post request,  but we need a GET request
                    var loc = window.location;
                    window.location = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname + loc.search;
                 }
                else
                {
                    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( { value: progressVal });
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Request Error !!!!");
            }
        });
    };

{% if progressScriptActive %}
    $(function()
    {
        intervalHandler = setInterval("refresh()", 2000);
    });
{% endif %}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You have to reference jquery files which you downloaded from  http://jqueryui.com/download/ with a selected UI theme (without you will see nothing!)

Downloaded the zip and reference these unziped jquery sources in the "hellogaequeue.py" file.
Your folder structure should look like:

```
hellogaequeue
    -templates
         -counter.html
    -static
         - jquery-ui.css
         - jquery-ui.js
         - ... and all the other unziped files/folders
    -app.yaml
    -hellogaequeue.py
    -queue.yaml
```

and for the app.yaml you have to add:

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

I know this is not a clean solution, because of the 'progressScriptActive' trick (which only starts a polling intervall after a post-request ). 
So if someone has a cleaner solution I would be glad to see it.

Comment: The myProgressValue should be saved in the database of gae. Because Google will start new Instances of the app, therefore all global parameters are reset to initial value. The GAE log says : "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, 
and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. 
This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."