# Loading bar in flask using stream_with_context on google app engine flexible environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, generator, gunicorn

Use case - some user data is getting loaded in the backend (flask), and the progress is shown on the frontend through a loading bar. The backend has a generator which loads the data and keeps **yielding** the progress (this generator is returned as a response using stream_with_context). The frontend queries the flask view using a javascript **EventSource** object.

Code:

```
@app.route("/progress", methods=['GET'])
def progress():
    gen = get_user_data()
    return Response(stream_with_context(gen), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')

def get_user_data():
    n = 100 (number of data points to be loaded)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        #load data
        yield "data:" + str((float(i)/(n))*100) + "\n\n"
    yield "data:" + "close" + "\n\n"
```

This works fine on my local environment. However, when I deploy it on **google app engine flexible environment**, the loading bar goes directly from 0 to 100. That is, instead of the front end getting updates each time my generator yields, I'm getting all the EventSource messages at once (when the generator has finished execution).

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn --timeout 240 -b :$PORT app:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 2

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Any idea on how I can get this to work on google app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"An EventSource instance opens a persistent connection to an HTTP server", according to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource). This solution is not going to work in App Engine according to the explanation provided [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/15623azjjf/server-sent-events-using-channels-api):

> You could attempt to declare "Content-Type: text/event-stream" on your
>   own vanilla App Engine handler, and use an EventSource
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource
>
> object in the browser to initiate a keep-alive connection. The problem
>   is, App Engine waits for the handler on your app to `return fully before flushing the buffer and sending the response data`. You can find
>   this documented here:
>
> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/requests#Java_Responses
>   for java
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Responses
>   for python
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/requests#PHP_Responses 
>   for php
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/requests#Go_Responses 
>   for go.
>
> What this means in practice is that your stream will not be
>   "kept-alive" and will close each time one response is sent. Or, if you
>   implement your server-sent event code server-side as most people do,
>   it will buffer up all of its responses and finally send them all only
>   when it terminates.

There are a couple of complex workarounds currently available:

- Using [Pusher](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-pusher): "Pusher is a hosted API for sending real-time, bi-directional messages via WebSockets to apps and other INternet-connected devices." This is not an official product documentation, but its author is a Googler.
- If you use [Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine#getting_started_with_firebase_realtime_database): "You can use App Engine in conjunction with the Firebase Realtime Database to send immediate updates to browser and mobile clients without a persistent streaming connection to the server or long polling. "

A simpler way will be available soon, according to message #231 in [this issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35886348). Flex WebSockets Beta launch will be available soon but for Standard environment, it is "at least a year away". Star the issuetracker post if you want to get automatic notifications on comments and updates.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I have decided to go ahead with the approach mentioned in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240597/progress-bar-in-google-app-engine The approach is: using task queues to set the progress of data loading, and polling from my client OR using the channel API to enable the client to get updates, instead of using javascript's EventSource.

Comment: I already saw that post AND checked that  Channel API was deprecated on [October 2017](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/release-notes#oct_27_2016) since the post dates from 2012. I am not sure if it is possible somehow with task queues, but good luck!